# Not able to get mysql running on my mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to install mysql on my mac but unable to start server. When I try to start mysql server, I get this error in the logs: Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied. Can't create/write to file ~/Downloads/mysql-5.5.32-osx10.6-x86_64/data/`HOSTNAME`.pid. I have symlinked /usr/local/mysql to ~/Downloads/mysql-5.5.32-osx10.6-x86_64. And all files/directories under /usr/local/mysql and ~/Downloads/mysql-5.5.32-osx10.6-x86_64 are owned by mysql. I'm trying start mysql server as root. Searched everywhere for this, but no luck. I tried with mysql 5.5 and 5.6. Same problem with both the versions. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highly recommend you install mysql using Homebrew. To do this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
brew install mysql
```

The output of the second command may give you a few extra steps. Follow them and you should be set.

Comment: I second homebrew, by far the easiest way to get it running. And because you have to start it manually by default, you don't have a dummy daemon running in the background whenever you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start it as an administrator. Write `sudo` and a space followed by the command you will use to start MySQL.

Comment: Yes I'm starting as root. Getting this error even then. I'm clueless why it is not able to create the PID file

Answer (score 0):

Use below permission to grant permissions:
check your mysqld location, mine is this:

do this:
ls -ld /usr/local/var/mysql

sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/var/mysql